# Using event listener on p tags

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble changing the the `h1 tag` when I click on either of the `p tags`. I am having trouble with looping through the `p tags`, extracting the value and changing the title with that data value. As of now I only get the error Cannot read property `value` of `undefined`.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  'use strict';

  const p_array = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  const count = p_array.length;

  //loop through a list of elements.
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    const p = p_array[i];

    p.addEventListener("click", function() {

      const tag = p.getElementsByTagName('p');

      document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = tag.dataset.value;

    })
  }
});
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Title</h1>
<p data-value="One">Click to change title to One</p>
<p data-value="Two">Click to change title to Two</p>
<p data-value="Three">Click to change title to Three</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  'use strict';

  const p_array = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  const count = p_array.length;

  //loop through a list of elements.
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    const p = p_array[i];

    p.addEventListener("click", function() {

      //const tag = p.getElementsByTagName('p');

      document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = p.dataset.value;

    })
  }
});
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Title</h1>
<p data-value="One">Click to change title to One</p>
<p data-value="Two">Click to change title to Two</p>
<p data-value="Three">Click to change title to Three</p>
```

Comment: Was searching for a way to implement a event listener where I didn't know the id/name/etc... beforehand, this really helped me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` returns collection of nodes. If you are interested in current `p` just use `this` or event target:

```
p.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  const tag = e.target
  // or const tag = this

  document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = tag.dataset.value;
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there a long way to extract the data set from the p tag? Or would it make sense to just use this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  'use strict';

  const p_array = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  const count = p_array.length;

  //loop through a list of elements.
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    const p = p_array[i];

    p.addEventListener("click", function() {
      // Here the `this` keyword refers to the element that is clicked
      document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = this.dataset.value;

    })
  }
});
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Title</h1>
<p data-value="One" data-doo="foo">Click to change title to One</p>
<p data-value="Two">Click to change title to Two</p>
<p data-value="Three">Click to change title to Three</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Use [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to build an Array from the HTMLCollection returned from `getElementsByTagName()`.

**Step 2:**

Set an event listener on each element and use the clicked elements `data-value` to change `#title`

---

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    'use strict';
    
    Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("p")).forEach(ele => {
        ele.addEventListener("click", function() {
            document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = ele.dataset.value;
        })
    });
});
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Title</h1>
<p data-value="One">Click to change title to One</p>
<p data-value="Two">Click to change title to Two</p>
<p data-value="Three">Click to change title to Three</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick (javascript only)
p.getAttribute('data-value'); returns the value of the specified attribute

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    'use strict';

    const p_array = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    const count = p_array.length;

    //loop through a list of elements.
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        const p = p_array[i];

        p.addEventListener("click", function(){

          alert(p.getAttribute('data-value'));
            document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = p.getAttribute('data-value');

        });
    }
});
```